# Update Twitter status with more than 4 images/more than 1 video

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots

I made a twitter bot that upload images and videos, it works but it can only upload 1 image and 1 video in 1 tweet. So i want to improve it so i can upload multiple images/videos, but twitter has 4 images or 1 video limit in 1 tweet. I already figured it out how to upload 4 images in 1 tweet, but that's not how i want it.
So the idea is to maxed out twitter upload limit then if reach the limit, upload it into a twitter thread. For example in the folder contain 5 images and 2 video the bot will tweet 1 video - reply previous tweet with 1 video - reply previous tweet with 4 images - then reply previous tweet with 1 image or vice versa.
I got some ideas from [dumpbot](https://github.com/ftrain/dumpbot) and [threader](https://github.com/choldgraf/threader) on github but still don't know how to implement my idea to those scripts. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @NickPerkins I'm sorry if i gave you that impression, I’ve literally just started to learn how to code last week so i almost know nothing at this momment. Not a good excuse but yeah...thanks for the advice, i've learnt something today.

Answer (score 1):

I think i kinda figured it out, it works. For now it is only for image upload tho...

```python
import tweepy as tp
import time
import os

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''


#Twitter login.
auth = tp.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)
api = tp.API(auth)


os.chdir('images')
media_ids = []
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    res = api.media_upload(filename)
    media_ids.append(res.media_id)


medid1= media_ids[:4]
print(medid1)
medid2 = media_ids[4:8]
print(medid2)
medid3 = media_ids[8:]
print(medid3)

# tweet with multiple images
if medid1:
    tweet1 = api.update_status(status='tweet1', media_ids=medid1)
    tweetid1 = tweet1.id_str
    time.sleep(1)

if medid2:
    tweet2 = api.update_status(status='tweet2', media_ids=medid2, in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid1)
    tweetid2 = tweet2.id_str
    time.sleep(1)

if medid3:
    tweet3 = api.update_status(status='tweet3', media_ids=medid3, in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid2)
    tweetid3 = tweet3.id_str
    time.sleep(1)
```